# apt-get update could not connect to

Tags: updates

Hi trying to get Ubuntu updating on Beaglebone Black board and get errors: I used BBB-eMMC-flasher-ubuntu-16.04.2-console-armhf-2017-06-08-2gb
Install ok. Network ok. sudo apt-get update errors:

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubu... xenial InRelease
Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (172.1.8.1), connection timed out
Err:2 .......
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubu... Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (172.1.8.1), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch ..., connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

There were more errors with links where the .... is. I had to take links out, because could post otherwise.
ubuntu@arm:~$
How to resolve?

Comment: Is the internet connection ok?

Comment: Yes how did you check if "Network ok."? Can you `ping google.com`? Maybe your DNS config failed

Comment: network works, i.e. ping, However all resolves to 172.1.8.1ubuntu@arm:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.1.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.1.8.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=239 time=751 ms
Tried already to set DNS 8.8.8.8.in resolv.conf and others but all names are resolved in 172.1.8.1 No clue why this address is always used

Comment: SOLVED. Used the newer image BBB-eMMC-flasher-ubuntu-16.04.2-console-armhf-2017-06-12-2gb from https://rcn-ee.com/rootfs/2017-06-12/ and that did the update and pings without problems

Answer (score 0):

To fix that problem on my BeagleBone:

change `etc/dnsmasq.d/SoftAp0`

```
dhcp-option-force=option:dns-server,192.168.8.1
```

to your DNS, in my case 192.168.1.1

```
dhcp-option-force=option:dns-server,192.168.1.1
```

and delete

```
address=/#/172.1.8.1
```

Then

```
sudo service dnsmasq restart
```